# 100s of errors that all go away when I view them?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, ide

I have hundreds of errors saying type or namespace doesn't exist (some are types and some are namespaces). When I click to view the error it initially opens the file and shows the squiggly line under code in question, however within a second or two the squiggly line disappears and so does the error.

After I finish opening up all the files with "errors", all the errors disappear and it compiles fine. However, if I close any the files then the error reappears for that file.

This happened after I tried to merge branches. Not really sure how to proceed to find the root of the issue, or whether there even is a real issue... maybe this is just some bug in Visual Studio and I need to do something to clear some kind of cache to fix the problem?

Please advise.

Update:

I have tried all of tymtam's suggestions but to no avail.

However, after deleting the .vs folder, now the errors don't even go away when I open the files so I can no longer build by doing that either.

I am thinking the error may have something to do with dll versions or something like that but I have tried to rebuild and replace all dlls with latest ones and that hasn't helped either.

Comment: Making sure the referenced project has the same .NET Framework-version fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that my problem was that I had thought that I had updated the main csproj file, but had neglected to do so. I had updated all the other ones. Simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did these two things to fix my problem:

1. I used WinMerge to copy files from the old branch over everything in the new branch for the application in question.
2. I updated the framework on the project to the latest version.

Originally, I did those two steps except I used TFS to merge the old branch to the new (instead of using WinMerge to copy/overwrite files) and accepted the old version for all conflicts.

This was the nuclear option as I lost any changes that were made in the new branch :(. I have a copy that I can use WinMerge to try to manually merge changes back in but it's definitely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

*IntelliSense*, which is likely the source of these errors, sometimes takes time to adjust to changes caused by switching branches (or more generally code changes that happen suddenly).

Here are the steps that should help, in order:

1. (Re)building the solution
2. Restarting Visual Studio
3. Closing Visual Studio and deleting `.vs` folder in the root of the solution folder.

Finally you can see if the errors are 'real' by changing what the Error List window shows to `Build Only`. I would recommend to have it as '*Build + IntelliSense*' normally, and using *Build Only* only on special occasions.

[image]

---

## Focus on the 1st error

More generally, when dealing with a large number of errors it's not a bad idea to look at the first one only, solve it, and build the code. A single syntax error can result in many errors and trying to solve the 2nd and subsequent errors would be futile.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried restarting VS multiple times to no avail.  I'll try your last suggestion tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: Deleting *.vs* folder is quite reliable for solving this issue. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, I have tried all of the above to no avail. :(

Comment: Before, when I clicked on a file with a problem it would open and show the squiggly line under the error momentarily but then it would go away and so would the error. So by the time I ended up opening all the files in question (probably 50 or so) then all the errors would disappear and I could build. However, after deleting the .vs folder now when I do the same the errors do not disappear even when I open the files (the squiggly line goes away and the file doesn't show it as an error, but it still shows up as an error in the Error List). And this is with "Build Only" selected. So frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was an outdated version of the .net framework. The new assemblies I was referencing were 4.8 based but my projects were targetting the 4.6.1 framework. Updating the project files to target 4.8 fixed it.

Comment: +1. this is what happened to me. The new assembly was built with 4.7.2 and the exe project refer to it was still 4.0. Hence intellisense error goes away (because the namespace and function matched) when viewing the code but build error still there. Changing the exe project to 4.7.2 fix the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, make sure you also look at the warnings (possibly information messages).
In my case, I had them turned off to focus on the errors only and missed the fact that my two projects were set to different versions of the .NET framework.